# Wp admin page isn't accessible

Tags: wordpress, admin

When I go to http://www.cowrubber.com/wp-admin

the url changes to 
http://cowrubber.com/wp-admin/cowrubber.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fcowrubber.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Somehow I just can't access the admin page to login.

I have copied the site from an test site on the localhost. And changed the url's in the database to the new ones but due to unknown reasons I just can't access the admin site.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the issue is but if you go this link: http://cowrubber.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fcowrubber.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 you will get to your admin page

Comment: That takes me to the login indeed:) but when i login i am redirected to cowrubber.com/cowrubber.com/wp-admin and then i just got a blank page somehow.

Comment: Try taking out the duplicate cowrubber.com/ that might take you to the wp-admin page, however this doesn't fix your issue. I assume its a site url OR htaccess issue but I cant be sure of that without delving deeper.

Answer (score 0):

When you move a wordpress to a differently named domain, it is not ehough to just search and replace in the database, because wordpress (sadly) store a lot of things in serveral table in serialized format.

So what you need to do is, in your case:

- **Create a backup** of your local database.
- **Create a backup** of your current production database and file.
- Delete all the files from your production server, and drop all table from production database.
- Copy all files to your production server from localhost.
- Import the local database to production database.
- **Do not open the production wordpress site in the browser!**
- Go to here, and download the newest script: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
- Unzip it into a `wp_replace` directory.
- Upload this directory to your document root, where `wp-conifg.php` is.
- Go to the http://example.com/wp_replace/
- Fill the `From` and `To` fields, without `http://` and without trailing slash. Eg: `somethinog.localhost` to 'example.com`
- Live run it. You will see, how many records changed in wich tables.
- Delete this `wp_replace` directory. If you leave it, add a `htpasswd` to it otherwise anybody can crash your db.
- Go to the WP admin, navigate to `Options -> Permalinks`. Push save.
- Now you can use your new domin :)